# Is it any issue to persist state to localstorage in middleware, Redux?

Tags: redux

Here is a sample pseudo code to persist state to local storage in middleware - Redux.

```js
function saveState({ getState }) { // saveState middleware
  return next => action => {


    // Call the next dispatch method in the middleware chain.
    const returnValue = next(action)

    console.log('state after dispatch', getState())
    // Save state to localstorage here!!

    // This will likely be the action itself, unless
    // a middleware further in chain changed it.
    return returnValue
  }
}

const store = createStore(todos, ['Use Redux'], applyMiddleware(saveState))
```

The questions are:

1. Will this solution cause any problem?
2. Is it better to use store.subscribe(()=>  // localStorage here) ...

Comment: Would [Redux-Persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) work for what you are trying to do?

Comment: @DrewReese Hi Drew, I knew Redux-Persist. I just wonder if persisting state to local storage in middleware will cause problem.

Comment: I see. No, I don't suspect it would cause any problem if you are just saving state to localStorage.